# UIAlertController popoverPresentationController covering sourceView

Tags: ios, ipad, uialertcontroller

I'm setting the properties for a `UIAlertController` like so:

```
alertController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sourceView.bounds
```

Presenting this `alertController` on an iPad displays a popover as expected, with the tip of the popover arrow in the exact centre of the `sourceView`, as expected. However, this covers up part of the content of my `sourceView`. Is there something I can do so that content won't be covered? For example if the arrow is pointing down, the arrow tip will be at the top of my `sourceView`. And if the arrow is pointing up, the arrow tip will be at the bottom of my `sourceView`. I could manipulate the `sourceRect`, but I can't know ahead of time what the arrow direction is going to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow *should* be pointing to the outside of the sourceRect relative to the sourceView. When you give sourceView.bounds as the sourceRect that should be the entire source view. So should not overlap.

Set a break point in there and step through and verify everything is as you expect.

Comment: @Ben William I tried the same and my alert was shown outside the bounds of sourceView.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The issue was elsewhere in my code. Thanks!